# Running Python's nose unit-tests in GAE sandbox

Tags: python, google-app-engine, nose

I have a simple `lxml` parser hosted on Google App Engine with some `nose` tests. I know how to run tests in terminal with `--with-gae` but I want to be able to run tests also in production environment under some URL like `/unit-tests`. I can run nose tests like:

```
import nose
nose.run()
```

but it ends with error:

```
File "/Users/martin/develop/gae/artova-kina/nose/core.py", line 168, in parseArgs
    os.chdir(self.config.workingDir)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'chdir'
```

which makes sence to me, because `chdir` is probably not available inside GAE sandbox but I think there should be some workaround. Has anyone tried something like this?

Comment: At the end I didn't use nosetests on GAE server and made my own test discovery tool and I used with standard Python's unittest framework.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using nose, but I have seen similar problems running on "live server" testcases (using django-nonrel).

It looks to me that dev_appserver is designed to be single threaded.  During each wsgi entry, it reconfigures a bunch python system objects, for example os is reconfigured so you can't write to the filesystem (which you can't do on appengine).  These reconfigurations are restored after the wsgi request is handled (I think).

However, if you have another thread doing anything while the request is being handled, you'll run into these problems.  You'll need to synchronize your thread to not run while dev_appserver.py is processing a request.  Since it's a threading issue, it's kinda random.  I find that my tests sometimes pass, sometimes fail with this problem.

Since I'm not the only person running into this we should file an issue to see if the GAE guys can make it easier for us.

Comment: There is a `threadsafe` option in GAE `app.yaml` and I tried to set it to false but it didn't help :(.

Comment: The threadsafe option allows multiple threads to run inside the web server.  The problem is when you have another thread running outside the server.  Do you know if your nose test is launching dev_appserver in a separate thread, or another process entirely?  I thought it might be ok if it's launched in another process.